# Problem in searching through Solr

Tags: tomcat, solr

I deployed solr.war in Tomcat server. its admin page running fine. But the problem is i am not getting the search results since there is no indexes available. i did what link http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrTomcat#Single_Solr_app says. but i am not getting when there is no data then how i will find the indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Do you see any index at

```
http://yourserver:8080/solr/
```

Comment: http://localhost:8080/solr/ is welcome page which provides you to search text. But the problem is i am not getting the search results. bcoz there are no indexes. For this i hav to set the index directory path. i want to know how can i set it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you working on multicore? If so, in Tomcat you have to mention this:

```
“%SOLRPATH%\multicore”
```

Comment: @Bob Yoplait,Marshal: No i am working on single solr app. i just want to know do i need to configure path for indexes. actually the problem is i downloaded source code of solr web application from net which is ruuning on server jetty, where u run the command java -jar post.jar *xml and it indexes all your xml files but how can i achieve in Tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

links do not work in the comments...
From the solr distribution, copy example/solr in your solr home /etc/tomcat6/solr. Make sure /var/data/solr owner is tomcat6:tomcat6. Then you need something like solrj to fill up the index. You can also use q csv file with curl like:

```
curl "http://localhost:8080/solr/fnac/update/csv?commit=true&separator=%7c&header=false&fieldnames=id,reference,ean13,title,desc,mark,cat,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,," --data-binary @marchand.csv -H 'Content-type:text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1'"
```

Also, some notes on solr:

http://swiss-knife.blogspot.com/search?q=solr

**Edited on May 16th, 2011:**
On Tomcat, in catalina.sh, I do:
JAVA_OPTS="-Dsolr.solr.home=/etc/tomcat6/solr -Djava.awt.headless=true -server -XX:NewSize=256m -XX:MaxNewSize=256m -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:+DisableExplicitGC"